# iOS pushNotice redirect - stroyboard

Tags: ios, push-notification

I would like to redirect to the specific view when touching the push notice alarm outside the app. I've write some code like this...

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
  if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive){
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ChatViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatView"];                           
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
}
```

It did redirect to the chatViewController, but only chatViewController have been launch. Do I have to write down the whole `Controller` structure of my app, or there are other ways to do so?

The structure of my app is a UITabBarViewController with four tab...

tab1 > UINavigationController > UICollectionViewController > UIViewController

tab2 > UINavigationController > UICollectionViewController

tab3 > UINavigationController > UITableView > UITableView(chatViewController)

tab4 > UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to get viewController in storyboard. So I can directly do this...

```
    UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *nav = tab.viewControllers[0];
    tab.selectedViewController = nav;
    myViewController *vc = (ChatListViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    [vc.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create the stack of view-controllers.

First you say to push to the first table view controller, mentioning it a push coming. You can invoke a push constructor. Below is the code in UITableViewController*.

tab3 > UINavigationController > UITableViewController.

```
- (id)initWithPush:(Chart*)chart {
    self  = [self initWithNibName:<#(NSString *)#> bundle:<#(NSBundle *)#>];
    if (self) {
        [self pushToChart:chart];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)pushToChart:(Chart*)chart {
    // add the code to push to next Chart-View-Controller
}
```

Comment: Should I set the UITabBarController to the rootViewController and set its viewControllers like what I did in storyboard?